# How to change code output color in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to change the color of code output which redirected to zsh integrated terminal at VS Code (macOS)but with no result. It's quite simple to change the Theme in settings or only text/background/cursor color but it's quite challenging to change only colour of code output (I want to do this in order to make it easier to see where is output of my script and where is terminal data).

Firstly I tried this at settings.json:

```json
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
     "-dumb", 
     "-c", 
     "echo -e '\\e[31m'"
]
```

But VS Code told me:

> This is now deprecated. recommendation tells: 'the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile in `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows` and setting its profile name as the default in `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows`. This will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that will change in the future.`

Next step was trying this:

```json
"zsh": {
     "path": "zsh",
     "args": [
         "-l",
         "echo '\u001b[31m'"
     ]
}
```

But I got this error:

```
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l', 'echo '[31m''" failed to launch (exit code: 127).
```

I know that it's possible to use such constructions in the code

```py
print("\033[34mHello, world!\033[0m")
```

but... Is it possible to set up VS Code?

Comment: you can customize the theme terminal colors by theme

Answer (score 0):

Open the VS Code settings by pressing Command +, After that, search for `Workbench` in the search bar. In the `Color Customizations` section you can find `Edit in settings.json`. Then you can edit the `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` to change any color.If the changes do not apply, try restarting the terminal. You can refer [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).